# Как работает данное условие item.id !== id в коде React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пишу todo list на хуках, надо добавить действие на удаление элемента из массива.
На просторах интернета нашел следующий код

```
const deleteItem = (id) => {
setTodo(
  todo.filter(item => {
    return item.id !== id
  })
  
);
```

}

Объясните пожалуйста как работает это условие

item.id !== id

Comment: сравнивает `item.id` с `id`

Comment: Нда. Человек не понимает, что делает операция сравнения, не зная, очевидно, не то что основ языка, а даже базисов алгоритмики и программирования, а уже в какой-то React полез

Comment: Вы бы лучше ответ на вопрос дали, а не начали говорить, что я ничего не знаю( не знаю с чего вы это взяли). В добавок, если человеку что то непонятно и он начинает разбираться это скорее хороший тон. Вы же кидаете такой ответ, это как минимум показатель какой вы человек. Так что не завидую людям, что работают с вами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Происходит перебор массива с условием item.id !== id. Если условие выполняется, то в новый масив запишется item. Если item.id будет равен id, то условие не выполнится и item не попадет в новый массив. Проще говоря, если id = 10, то в новый массив попадут все элементы кроме item.id = 10